# python, operation on big pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame named Joined with 5 fields:

```
product | price | percentil_25 | percentil_50 | percentile_75
```

for each row I want to class the price like this:

if the price is below percentil_25 I'm giving to this product the class 1, and so on

So what I did is:

```
classe_final = OrderedDict()
classe_final['sku'] = []
classe_final['class'] = []

for index in range(len(joined)):
    classe_final['sku'].append(joined.values[index][0])
    if(float(joined.values[index][1]) <= float(joined.values[index][2])):
        classe_final['class'].append(1)
    elif(float(joined.values[index][2]) < float(joined.values[index][1]) and float(joined.values[index][1]) <= float(joined.values[index][3])):
        classe_final['class'].append(2)
    elif(float(joined.values[index][3]) < float(joined.values[index][1]) and float(joined.values[index][1]) <= float(joined.values[index][4])):
        classe_final['class'].append(3)
    else:
        classe_final['class'].append(4)
```

But as my DataFrame is quite big it's taking forever.

Do you have any idea how I could do this quicker?

Comment: Sorry are you just wanting to determine the class of the produce dependent on where the price falls in each percentile? so < 25 class 1, >=25 and < 50 class 2 .....

Comment: Sorry I just noticed you are using an ordered dict to store your values so my answer is incorrect, what are you trying to produce? Your code is going to result in a dict with the product as the key and then a list of each class a price for that product belongs too, is that correct? Could you show a toy sample dataset and expected output

Comment: As an output I just want a DataFrame with 2 fields: product | class @EdChum

Comment: So you're essentially building just a classification dataframe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# build an empty df
df = pd.DataFrame()
# get a list of the unique products, could skip this perhaps
df['Product'] = other_df['Sku'].unique()
```

2 ways, define a func and call apply

```
def class(x):
    if x.price < x.percentil_25:
        return 1
    elif x.price >= x.percentil_25 and x.price < x.percentil_50:
        return 2:
    elif x.price >= x.percentil_50 and x.price < x.percentil_75:
        return 2:
    elif x.price >= x.percentil_75:
        return 4

df['class'] = other_df.apply(lambda row: class(row'), axis=1)
```

another way which I think is better and will be much faster is we could add the 'class' column to your existing df and use `loc` and then just take a view of the 2 columns of interest:

```
joined.loc[joined['price'] < joined['percentil_25'], 'class'] =1
joined.loc[(joined['price'] >= joined['percentil_25']) & (joined['price'] < joined['percentil_50']), 'class'] =2
joined.loc[(joined['price'] >= joined['percentil_50']) & (joined['price'] < joined['percentil_75']), 'class'] =3
joined.loc[joined['price'] >= joined['percentil_75'], 'class'] =4

classe_final = joined[['cku', 'class']]
```

Just for kicks you could use a load of `np.where` conditions:

```
classe_final['class'] = np.where(joined['price'] > joined['percentil_75'], 4, np.where( joined['price'] > joined['percentil_50'], 3, np.where( joined['price'] > joined['percentil_25'], 2, 1 ) ) )
```

this evaluates whether the price is greater than percentil_75, if so then class 4 otherwise it evaluates another conditiona and so on, may be worth timing this compared to loc but it is a lot less readable

Comment: thanks, I'm definitely using the second solution! it's quite fast, thanks again!

Comment: @user1754181 you can upvote too ;), the thing to take from this is to avoid loops and using apply unless it is not possible, what you want to do is to find if you vectorise your operation, that is perform your operation on the entire dataframe or series rather than a row at a time.

Comment: yes I know what you mean, I'm more use to sql, pandas is kinda new for me

Answer (score 0):

Another solution, if someone asked me to bet which one is the fastest I'd go for this:

```
joined.set_index("product").eval(
    "1 * (price >= percentil_25)"
    "  + (price >= percentil_50)"
    "  + (price >= percentil_75)"
)
```

Comment: It's more an improvement in readability and maintainability than in performance :). Didn't test it though, `loc` is pretty fast. @user1754181, do you have any test data available?

Comment: Checking on my machine that last implementation is one order of magnitude faster (30ms vs 300ms on a dataframe with 1M rows) than the accepted solution.